# Extjs autosize grid columns to fit content in Modern toolkit

Tags: extjs

How can you automatically size grid columns such that the column is the width necessary to show the contents?

This is possible in Classic but does not seem possible in the Modern toolkit.

Comment: Just curious, how is this done in Classic?

Comment: I was using the autoSize function: e.g. myGrid.getColumns()[1].autoSize()

Comment: Ah, I see... I was thinking it was some setting you could have on a grid/column, but I'm assuming you called this method somewhere after your data loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It looks this was finally sorted in 7.0.0 and the autoSize method was added to Ext.grid.column.Column to bring it into parity with Classic.

It doesn't work properly in 7.0.0 to 7.3.1 though and fails to set the width to the correct size for the text. Typical poor quality

Answer (score 0):

'Ext.grid.column.Column.autoSize()' method was implemented in v7.0. It will not work on flexed columns (AFAIK in classic toolkit is the same). Have a look at the following sample:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button 1',
                    handler: function(btn) {
                        var grid = this.up('panel').down('grid');
                        grid.getColumns().forEach(function(column) {
                            column.autoSize();
                        })
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'grid',
                height: 200,
                store: store,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email'
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    flex: 1 // Will not autoSize.
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```